# При удалении символа из UITextField курсор не остаться на том же месте

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

При удалении символа из UITextField курсор не остаться на том же месте, а перемещается в конец строки

+38 (серым цветом) это маска которая добавляется как только пользователь начинает вводить номер

```html
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.textField {

            
            let returnKey = (string as NSString).length == 0
            
            
            let oldLength = textField.text!.length
            let replacementLength = string.length
            let rangeLength = range.length
            
            let newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength
            return newLength <= 18 || returnKey
            
           
        }
        
        return true
 }
}
```

[image: курсор перескочил в конец строки]

Comment: я так понимаю вопрос в том, что должен. покажите код, в частности `shouldChangeCharactersIn `

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko приложила код к вопросу , да суть в том, что курсив должен оставаться на месте удаления символа , а не перескакивать в конец строки

Comment: Посмотрите ответ тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift